# Event Reference in Function

Tags: javascript

If I have a object, with a function that captures every form on the page as an array:

```
var object = 
{
 var forms = document.getElementsByTagName("form");
```

And I add an event listener to it (W3C DOM 2 Event Model, I don't care about IE for this example):

```
addEventListener = function(target, type, listener)
{
 target.addEventListener(type, listener, false);
};
```

And I call (normally a loop, but lets just take one example):

```
addEventListener(forms[i], "change", changeListener);
```

And changeListener is equal to:

```
changeListener: function(event)
{
 updateDependents(this);
}
```

And updateDependents equals:

```
updateDependents: function(form)
   {
    ...
   }
};
```

can someone explain to me the progression of arguments (i.e. what "this" and "event" are equal to)?

To me, it looks like:

For the form in question (forms[i]), an event listener is being added based upon a "change" event, and the action to be taken is "changeListener".

changeListener takes an argument of (event), so it must be referencing potential event that forms[i] has(?). [not sure about this]

It then calls "updateDependents(this)"... what is the "this" here? Is it the form that is identified in the "target" argument of the "addEventListener" method, or is it the event argument that exists within the "changeListener(event)" method? [can someone please explain why it would be one over the other?]

Note: I'm obviously confused, so I apologize for any stupidity. Also, this is an excerpt from "Simply Javascript" by Sitepoint.

Cheers,

Sapiensgladio

Comment: That first code block in your question is not valid JavaScript.

Comment: Also, that book looks pretty questionable from the smarmy description of the contents on the Sitepoint website.  You may want to look into another book, like the classic O'Reilly book or Crockford's "JavaScript: The Good Parts". There are a **lot** of terrible, misleading books about JavaScript (and everything else for that matter :-)

Comment: @Pointy, yes - what I failed to communicate is that all of these are rolled up into an object ("object" in this instance). Hence why it doesn't close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JS `this` only gets a value in a few ways:

1. When calling `someObj.method()`, then `this === someObj`
2. Calling `method.call(someObj, ...)`, then `this === someObj`, and likewise for `method.apply(someObj, args)`
3. In Javascript 1.8.5 / ES5, by using [`Function.prototype.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

If a method is invoked simply as `method()` then `this === window` (or whatever the global object is if you're not in a browser).

DOM2's `addEventListener()` uses #2 above and sets `this` to be the element [from which the event was fired](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener).

Answer (score 1):

The event listener function is passed the events that happen; in this case, "change" events. The browser binds `this` to the DOM element.

Events "bubble" up the DOM (unless a handler tells a browser not to do that), so the first handler to be called will be the DOM element that was the direct cause or target of the event (that is, the form element that changed, in your case).  When all handlers for that element are called and have returned, the event is passed to the registered handlers on the parent object of the element.  Each time that happens, `this` is bound to the element directly related to the handler. The event object, however, refers to the original element with its "target" property.  That process continues up to the `<body>` element.